# USB connection between Android and Winlator

Tags: usb, windows, emulators

I have an Android tablet and have installed Winlator on it. It allows me to run Windows apps on Android. And I want to use it for an all-in-one animation setup and for that, I will need to connect the container of Winlator (Windows VM) to Android through a virtual USB connection.

Is there any way I could do that?

I tried searching for it on the web but there were no answers.